# relative Path after build with Vuejs CLI ignored

Tags: vuejs2

After building my app i need a semi absolute path, but only when using standard webpack init. How can i solve this as described below?

Apppath on Server:

```
domain/subfolder/subfolder2/index.html
```

If using

```
vue init webpack-simple myproject
```

I can set:

```
assetsPublicPath: ''
```

The result is that all files will be loaded correctly if placed next to the index.html, or in a subfolder3 (depending on config obviously).

If instead using

```
vue init webpack myproject
```

Setting of the assetPublicPath is being ignored unless i make it non empty. So

```
assetPublicPath: '/static'
```

works. But while it is kinda relative, the static folder may change as i don't have full control over the overlaying project. Because of that i want to just place the js file next to the html file and use an empty assetsPublicPath to be sure it will always work.

Why is this behavior changing due to the template used? How can i fix it?
I tried digging into all the different config files and failed to find any reason as to why this might happen.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you placing a js file in src next to the component and loading that files data into the component script tag:

```
<template>
    <div class="test">

    </div>
</template>

<script>

   import myClass from './myClass.js' 

    export default {
        name: 'test',
        data() {
            return {
                msg: '',
            }
        },
    methods: {
       something(){
       let foo = myClass.prop;
        }

      }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "../../assets/master";

</style>
```